# Sigma-complete Lindenbaum algebras?

Tags: lo.logic, boolean-algebras

Is there any calculus whose algebraization is a sigma-complete Lindenbaum algebra, i.e., a sigma-complete Boolean algebra after identification of equivalent formulas?

Comment: Could you clarify a little more exactly what you want? I believe that any Boolean algebra can arise as a Lindenbaum algebra for some suitably chosen first-order theory. And do you really want it to be $\sigma$-complete? In that case, it can't be countably infinite, since there is no countably infinite $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra. Once the algebra is infinite, you get a countable antichain, and then if it is $\sigma$-complete, you will find continuum many elements arising as joins of subsets of that antichain.

Comment: Joel, do you have a proof of your first assertion? for propositional theories is obvious, but for a first-order theory I'm not even sure it's true...

Comment: Let's see, I had in mind to build the theory out of the Boolean algebra itself, but I didn't think it all the way through. But I don't understand your comment, since I thought the problem was: given a Boolean algebra $\mathbb{B}$, find a first-order language and a theory $T$ in that language, such that the collection of formulas, modulo provable equivalence in $T$, is a copy of $\mathbb{B}$. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that was the assertion I was referring to. Is that true? Sorry, I cannot see it immediately, perhaps it's obvious to you...

Comment: I had thought it would be easy, but now I'm not sure whether it is true or not...

Comment: My current idea is to take the theory of the Boolean algebra $\mathbb{B}$ itself, in the language with a predicate $G$ on $\mathbb{B}$ and the scheme asserting that $G$ is a generic ultrafilter, that is, an ultrafilter meeting every definable dense subset. If $T$ is this theory, then $b\in G$ will have value $b$, and what else is there to say (modulo the theory)? So the corresponding Lindenbaum algebra seems to be very closely related to $\mathbb{B}$, if not $\mathbb{B}$ itself. Perhaps it should be a separate MO question, whether every Boolean algebra arises as a Lindenbaum algebra.

Comment: The Lindenbaum algebra of a complete theory is the two-element Boolean algebra, of course, which is Ord-complete. It is not hard, given any finite Boolean algebra, to make a first-order theory whose Lindebaum algebra is that Boolean algebra.

Comment: @Joel: That sounds interesting! I posted a new more general question here http://mathoverflow.net/q/162007/12976, but of course you are welcome to answer it for the Boolean case.

Answer (score 6):

There is no countably infinite $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra. Once the Boolean algebra is infinite, it must have an countably infinite antichain $A\subset\mathbb{B}$, and then by $\sigma$-completeness every subset $X\subset A$ will have a distinct join $\bigvee X$, making the Boolean algebra $\mathbb{B}$ have size at least continuum.

Perhaps you meant something else...?

Comment: OP does not say "infinte" anywhere...

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that, but of course, the finite Boolean algebras are trivially realized as Lindenbaum algebras. For example, in the theory asserting that there are exactly $n$ objects, with $n$ distinct constants $c_i$ and one more constant $d$, which must be one of the $c_i$. The assertions $d=c_i$ are atoms, and every assertion is some Boolean combination of the these atoms.

Comment: Or: the theory $T$ asserting that one of $n$ distinct finitely-axiomatizable complete theories holds. Each such theory is an atom, and every statement will be a join of atoms.